# Postgresql, Bad value for type BigDecimal : NaN

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

In Postgresql table we have field with type numeric(10, 2). When I try to select data from this field

```
select amount from vc_cashouts where id = 25721
```

I get this result (other records are correct):

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type BigDecimal : NaN
```

How can I correct this result? I need to export data from this column to file and i need to replace this NaN to for example default value

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `ResultSet.getBigDecimal()` to retrieve that value.

A `BigDecimal` can't represent `NaN` - only `java.lang.Double` can do that.

You need to change your code to use `ResultSet.getDouble()` or `ResultSet.getObject()` - the latter will return a BigDecimal or a `Double.NaN` depending on the value in the database.