# Pyspark read Postgres jdbc failed -- Bad value for type BigDecimal : NaN

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

I am running a spark job to read from Postgres through jdbc and write to HDFS. I receive an error of `Bad value for type BigDecimal : NaN`. Wondering why this can cause the problem and what's the solution?

Spark version: 3.3.1 
Postgres version: PostgreSQL 15.4

The pyspark script:

```
df = spark.read.jdbc(
    url = url,
    table = f'"{schema}"."{table}"',
    predicates = predicates,
    properties = properties
)
df.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('site').parquet(output_path)
```

Traceback:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 17 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 17.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 173) (xxx.xxx.xxx executor 4): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type BigDecimal : NaN
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toBigDecimal(PgResultSet.java:3249)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.toBigDecimal(PgResultSet.java:3258)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getNumeric(PgResultSet.java:2686)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBigDecimal(PgResultSet.java:2638)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getBigDecimal(PgResultSet.java:433)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$3(JdbcUtils.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$3$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(SortExec.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:245)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql, Bad value for type BigDecimal : NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64800433/postgresql-bad-value-for-type-bigdecimal-nan)

Answer (score 0):

From trackstace, exception is raised when reading the data from postgres by jdbc driver.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type BigDecimal : NaN
```

From similar stackoverflow page [Postgresql, Bad value for type BigDecimal : NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64800433/postgresql-bad-value-for-type-bigdecimal-nan), got that `BigDecimal` can't represent `NaN` - only `java.lang.Double` can do that.

Try typecasting that column to double using `query` option from spark read.